# Extract numerics from matrix A with logical matrix B

Tags: matrix, r

I have a matrix `A` containing numeric values and a matrix `B` containing 0/1s:

```
A <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5)
B <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 5, 5)

A                             B
1    6   11   16   21         0    0    1    0    0
2    7   12   17   22         0    0    0    0    1
3    8   13   18   23         0    0    0    0    1
4    9   14   19   24         0    0    1    0    0
5   10   15   20   25         0    0    1    0    0
```

I want to extract the elements of `A` where `B==1` in row order. The desired result is:

```
11 22 23 14 15
```

I've come up with two possible ways to do this:

```
#1
rowSums(A*B)

#2
t(A)[as.logical(t(B))]
```

It seems like there should be a better (more elegant or faster) way to do this...

Comment: Did you profile both?

Comment: @Mast -- Not yet. In my application, my matrices are fairly small, but they occur in a loop that is called many times.  I just figured that this would be a fairly common matrix operation, but I couldn't find "direct" way to implement it.

Comment: @Amstel made a point (that is now deleted), but maybe the "solution" is to store information as `t(A)` and `t(B)` instead of as `A` and `B` so that `A[B]` will work.

Comment: If how you store your information is up for changes/review, I'd recommend you replace the `B` matrix by a vector of indices, here `b = c(3, 5, 5, 3, 3)`. (I am basing my assumption that there is only one `1` per row from your `rowSums(A*B)` suggestion). Storing the info in a vector is the most memory efficient. Then you could do `A[cbind(seq_along(b), b)]`. Otherwise I find `t(A)[as.logical(t(B))]` elegant enough and it is probably very fast.

Answer (score 1):

While `rowSums(A*B)` looks pretty nice for me, you can also try

```
A[which(t(B) == 1, arr.ind = T)[,2:1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't have any substantial improvements, this is another way:

```
t(A)[t(B) == 1]
```